# Turn column headers into the first row of my df

Tags: pandas

I am looking forward to turn df headers to the first row of my df:

```
     Air    Unnamed:1  400.65    452.21    458.22
0    Wind       NaN   3835.83   3835.83   3813.18
1    Fire       NaN    989.05    989.75    981.31
2    Water      NaN   1617.00   1623.17   1614.64
```

Looking for this output:

```
       0         1      2        3          4
0     Air       NaN    400.65    452.21    458.22
1    Wind       NaN   3835.83   3835.83   3813.18
2    Fire       NaN    989.05    989.75    981.31
3    Water      NaN   1617.00   1623.17   1614.64
```

I have tried setting the header of the `read_html` function to -1 to see if it could make the header into the first row such as:

```
pd.read_html(route, flavor='html5lib',header=-1)
```

But didn't worked

Any idea on how to turn the headers into my first row of the df?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `header=None`:

```
pd.read_html(route, flavor='html5lib',header=None)
```

Comment: I thought that not considering the `header` parameter would act as `header=None`, however after inserting it , gave my desired output, Thank you!